# do the repetitive calculations outside the loop, not good enough. what to do?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, memory-management, vectorization

I have a function as follow. This function is going to be used in a `for` loop. In the loop only the variable `s` is changed in each iteration and the vectors `k1`, `k2`, `kt1` and `kt2` are constant. Since it is important for me to do the calculations in much less time, I don't want to calculate the same things which are related to my constant vectors in each iteration. So I can do the calculations related to vectors `k1`, `k2`, `kt1`and `kt2` before the loop. By this, in each iteration in `for` loop I just need to calculate `out2` then `out` and `eachkt` since they need `s`.

Here is the problem, to do what I said, I have to save all other variables and use them in `for` loop. Saving those variables, especially `out1` takes a lot of my RAM and really makes my laptop slow.

what do you suggest?

```
function eachkt = wholekt(k1,k2,kt1,kt2,s)

k1 = k1(:); k2=k2(:); kt1=kt1(:); kt2=kt2(:);
% k1_kbs1 = repmat(k1,1,numel(kt1))-repmat(kt1',numel(k1),1);
k1_kbs1 = bsxfun(@minus,k1,kt1');
% k2_kbs2 = repmat(k2,1,numel(kt2))-repmat(kt2',numel(k2),1);
k2_kbs2 = bsxfun(@minus,k2,kt2');
fork1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,prod(k1_kbs1,2),k1_kbs1);
[row, col] = find(isnan(fork1)); fork1(row,col)= eps;
fork2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,prod(k2_kbs2,2),k2_kbs2);
[row, col] = find(isnan(fork2)); fork2(row,col)= eps;
N1 = size(fork1,1);
N2 = size(fork2,1);
% foreachk = zeros(N1,N2,size(fork1,2)^2);
% D = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(fork1,[1 3 2]),fork2(:).'),N1,N2,[]);
out1 = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(fork1,[1 4 2 3]),permute(fork2,[4 1 3 2])),N1,N2,[]);
out2 = bsxfun(@times,out1,s);
out = reshape(sum(sum(out2,1),2),numel(kt1),numel(kt2));

a = 1./prod(bsxfun(@minus,kt1,kt1')+ eye(numel(kt1)),2);
b = 1./prod(bsxfun(@minus,kt2,kt2')+ eye(numel(kt2)),2);
c = a*b';
eachkt = c.*out ;


return
```

Here's an example:

```
k1 = rand(1,30);
k2 = rand(1,30);
kt1 = rand(1,10);
kt2 = rand(1,10);

for j = 1:100
    s = rand(30,30);
    eachkt = wholekt(k1,k2,kt1,kt2,s);
 end
```

Comment: Hmm those `bsxfun` codes giving me *deja-vu* feelings.

Comment: @Divakar yes sir, it is your edit :)

Comment: Remember to properly reference the code you have taken from other places!

Comment: @AnderBiguri It is my code which is edited before by asking in this site

Comment: Code in stakoverflow has a kind of GNU open license, meaning you can use it freely, but you need to reference it. Also, it is polite towards the person who wrote it for you, I believe.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Its actually a version of [CreativeCommons that requires attribution](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).